# Add "View More" button to product list

Tags: magento-1.9

I have a small Magento 1 shop. In product list I only have 1 button. 
Add to Cart (Forudbestil) marked with a red arrow.
[image]

I would like to add a button more called "More info" when pressed you get to the product detail page. Like when you press the image. I found a website with this. The blue arrow points at the "Add to cart" button and the red arrow points to the button I would like to add to my website. I have tried finding an extension to do the trick, but so far with no luck.
[image]

Comment: You would need access to the templates. It's not difficult; you can copy the same code that makes the link for the image and add a button with that link.

Answer (score 1):

Just add  `<a href="<?php echo $_product->getProductUrl() ?>">See more</a>` beside button tag

Answer (score 0):

Add this code in your **/app/design/frontend/rwd/default/template/catalog/product/list.phtml** file
after add to cart button

```
<p class="action">
  <a title="<?php echo $this->quoteEscape($this->__('View More')) ?>" class="button" href="<?php echo $_product->getProductUrl() ?>"><?php echo $this->__('View More') ?>
  </a>
</p>
```